# .Bat/CMD - Hiding "ERROR" with reg.exe >nul 2>&1

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, echo

```
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN (
   'REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\EA GAMES\Need for Speed Most Wanted" /v InstallDir'
) DO (set HBMU=%%B)
GOTO END
```

how I can add If %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto CLOSE to my code? because when i put under ) DO (set HBMU=%%B) it does not work.

[image]

Comment: Off the top of my head, `.../v InstallDir ^>nul 2^>^&1'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, *after completing the rest of the registry key on line 2*:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\..." /V "InstallDir" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "HBMU=%%B"
```

You cannot redirect both to `Nul` otherwise nothing will be output from the loop as variable `%%B`

**Edit**

Here's a complete script which should do what your commented code was supposed to do. *(As long as your software definitely places it's information in the registry according to the Operating System architecture)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "EAG=EA GAMES\Need for Speed Most Wanted"
Set "RKM=\"
Reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0"^
    /V "Identifier" 2>Nul|Find /I "x86">Nul||Set "RKM=\Wow6432Node\"
For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "HKLM\Software%RKM%%EAG%" /V^
 "InstallDir" 2^>Nul') Do Start "" "%%~B\unins000.exe"
Pause
```

Comment: "Skip=1" is important? What is it for?

Comment: It's not necessary, this type of registry search won't care if you ignore it. All that will happen is that it'll try to set the third tokens of the first line of output, _(the registry key)_, just before being overwritten by the value you need anyway.

Comment: OK. Anyway how I can add `If %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto CLOSE` to my code? because when i put under `) DO (set HBMU=%%B)` it does not work.

Comment: because even if registry key exist, it automatically goes to CLOSE.

Comment: Using the `For` loop there's no need to add an error level check, if the content of the command in your parentheses fails then there would be nothing to `Do`. If you want to see if there is an error run the command on its own in a cmd.exe window, `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\..." /V "InstallDir" `, and post exactly the contents of the window, not a screenshot!

Comment: I'm going to ask again; Run the command on its own in a cmd.exe window, `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\EA\NFSMW" /V "InstallDir"`, and post exactly the contents of the window, not a screenshot! It would probably be wise to also post the output of `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\EA\NFSMW" /V "InstallDir"` too. Please post that as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46507853/edit) to your question, _(as you can see above things become awkward inside comments)_. Additionally, I need to know which OS this is intended for, _(there are output differences between different versions)_!

Comment: Edited answer right now. _(what happened to "not a screenshot" and post the output of `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\EA\NFSMW" /V "InstallDir"` too)_.

Comment: So how does the script work for you, **without any modifications**?